# Savon and SoapUI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, soap, soapui, savon

I always use SoapUI before moving on with Savon to see if my URL is correct. Now this time I was given a URL that (probably from a project developed and hosted on a Windows machine), let's say it is this one:

> www.myservice.com/login/eeu.aspx?WSDL

Now when I try this, I get this:

```
Error loading [www.myservice.com/login/eeu.aspx?WSDL]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 3): '&'
```

SoapUI will also do HTTP requests right? not only SOAP (or am I confusing something here?)
Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with HTTP request (although SoapUI really performs it to get WSDL file in your case). Error message says that there is problem with parsing of the response -- it is not a well-formed XML document. Download WSDL of your service manually and check it with XML Validator. If it shows that XML is correct then it still may be related to some temporary problem (connections limit, resources shortage) that leads an ASP-based service to reply with error page that doesn't pass validation when this problem occurs.